# Android app: How to change fragments in Navigation Drawer

Tags: android, navigation, drawer

First of all I'm new to android developement and also to java.

I created a new project with the fragment navigation drawer,
but I don't really know how to add and change to those new fragments with it.
(It also seems like it doesnt change any fragments, just sets the TextView to a the selected position.)

Do you guys may know a good tutorial on how to do that (step by step)?
Or can you please give me a hint on how to do it?

**EDIT:**

I found a solution by myself:

```
@Override
public void onNavigationDrawerItemSelected(int position) {

    Fragment fragment;

    switch(position){
        case 0:
            fragment = new Fragment_main().newInstance(position+1);
            break;
        case 1:
            fragment = new Fragment_two().newInstance(position+1);
            break;
        default:
            fragment = new Fragment_main().newInstance(position +1);
            break;
    }

    // update the main content by replacing fragments
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
    fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.container, fragment)
            .commit();
}
```

you just have to add a switch into this method, and also create those classes (and layouts).

I hope this solution helps everyone who also struggles as begginer or with the navigation drawer :)

Comment: unfortunately this didn't help. Although I am using getSupportFragmentManager(), so that might be the problem. Changing it to getFragmentManager() brings up lots of errors.

Comment: @pbs could you post a code snippet for your problem?

Comment: @ ninety I worked out the problem in the end. The Eclipse auto-generated code I was using created static fragments using the Singleton pattern. Once I'd removed this pattern and just instantiated classes the normal way everything worked find.

Comment: @ninety Do you still need help with this question?

Comment: @ninety Can you please post your answer as a solution and mark it correct so that this is no longer "unanswered"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a solution by myself:

```
@Override
public void onNavigationDrawerItemSelected(int position) {

    Fragment fragment;

    switch(position){
        case 0:
            fragment = new Fragment_main().newInstance(position+1);
            break;
        case 1:
            fragment = new Fragment_two().newInstance(position+1);
            break;
        default:
            fragment = new Fragment_main().newInstance(position +1);
            break;
    }

    // update the main content by replacing fragments
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
    fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.container, fragment)
            .commit();
}
```

you just have to add a switch into this method, and also create those classes (and layouts).

I hope this solution helps everyone who also struggles as begginer or with the navigation drawer :)